# How do I mark up partially paid invoice in schema.org Invoice type

Tags: schema.org, invoice, json-ld

I am trying to provide JSON-LD output for an application that deals with invoices.

The invoices in that application can be partially paid (that is, customer may have paid part of the amount, but not all of it) and I need to be able to specify both in JSON-LD -- total invoice amount and the partially paid amount.

I have tried to find out, how others have approached this situation, but none of the official schemas (i've looked at schema.org and Goodrelations) seem to have out of the box recommendation for this type of situation.

My current idea is to express it as a custom *payment status* value, containing *`paidAmount`* property containing the partially paid amount like this:

```
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Invoice",
  ...
  "paymentStatus": {
    "@type": "PaymentStatusType",
    "name": "PaymentPartiallyPaid",
    "paidAmount": {
      "@type": "MonetaryAmount",
      "value": 42.31,
      "currency": "EUR"
    }
  },
  "totalPaymentDue": {
    "value": 200.00,
    "currency": "EUR"
  }
}
```

Is this valid approach?
Are there some existing examples of marking up partially paid invoice amounts?
Is there a better way?

**Edit:**

It turns out, you can not simply make up new attributes on the fly, when using linked data, so the scheme above is not valid JSON-LD, unless I manage to publish my extension to Invoice schema.

I am looking for a way to mark this up without extending the official schema...

Comment: You made the `paidAmount` up, right? This shouldn’t be done. If you need a property that doesn’t exist in Schema.org or another vocabulary, you should give it a URI that you control.

Comment: Yeah, at the moment I have no such luxury. I can make up a URI, but it won't reference a valid schema specification...

Answer (score 2):

I would use [minimumPaymentDue](http://schema.org/minimumPaymentDue) which is mentioned as the "minimum payment required at this time", in conjunction with totalPaymentDue which is the "total amount due". You can set the value of minimumPaymentDue to the difference between totalPaymentDue and the amount paid.

Also your totalPaymentDue was syntactically incorrect and setting the name is not how you set the value of an enum for paymentStatus of type PaymentStatusType — those problems have also been rectified below.

```
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Invoice",
  "paymentStatus": "https://schema.org/PaymentDue",
  "totalPaymentDue": {
    "@type": "MonetaryAmount",
    "value": 200.00,
    "currency": "EUR"
  },
  "minimumPaymentDue": {
    "@type": "MonetaryAmount",
    "value": 157.69,
    "currency": "EUR"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That sounds a lot like stretching the meaning of "minimumPaymentDue", but given our constraints at the moment, I guess this is okay...